# The verbs in combinatorics: Enumerating, counting, listing and all that

Tags: co.combinatorics, terminology, enumerative-combinatorics

Two closely related, but different tasks in combinatorics are

1. determining the *number* of elements in some set $A$, and
2. presenting all its *elements* one by one.

**Question:** What are some works in combinatorics literature that explicitly
consider the naming of these different tasks?

---

As a background, it seems that the terminology is sometimes
conflicting and confusing. In particular, *enumerating* can mean
either task. In computer science and algorithms it often refers to
task 2. In combinatorics it often refers to task 1, but not always.
*Pólya enumeration* is definitely task 1, not task 2 (indeed in
[this MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/94133/using-polyas-enumeration-theorem-for-explicit-generation-of-instances) it is pointed out that Pólya enumeration is
"not generally a good tool for actually listing").

For what it's worth, [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/enumerate) duly reports that
*enumerate* has meanings 1. to ascertain the number of: COUNT; 2. to
specify one after another: LIST.

Task 1 is also called *counting*, which seems unambiguous. But I have
seen "computing the number of elements *without actually counting
them*"!  Here *counting* seems to mean *tallying*, that is, keeping
a counter and incrementing by one whenever a new object is seen.

Task 2 admits many names, which also may indicate finer variations:

- *listing* the elements: Presenting a full listing, stored in some form (paper or computer file).
- *generating* the elements: A method that creates all the elements, one by one, but may not store them. Perhaps each element is examined, and then thrown away.
- *visiting*: similar to the previous, with a tone of computer science and data structures.
- *constructing*: similar, but with a more mathematical flavor. It suggests that creating even one object takes some effort, so it is not just "visiting".
- *classifying*: somewhat unclear, but often means something like generating the objects and counting how many of them have certain properties. But it might mean simply isomorph-free listing (in a sense, "classifying" the objects into isomorphism classes).
- Furthermore, task 2 is often emphasized with modifiers like "full", "explicit", "exhaustive", "actually", "one by one", "brute force" to set it apart from task 1.

*Enumerating* may also mean a more abstract task where elements are
equipped with indices and/or abstractly arranged in a potentially
infinite list, but one never actually constructs the list (as in
"enumerate all rational numbers").

To clarify my question: I am not asking for examples where the words
are just *used*, as in "In this paper we enumerate all Schluppenburger
contrivances of the second kind". I am interested in works that recognize
the difference of these tasks and make a conscious effort in defining
terminology, and perhaps explicitly comment on the usage.

---

Here are some that I have found:

- Knuth (TAOCP 4B §7.2.1) considers many verbs: *run through*
  possibilities, *look* at permutations, *enumerate*, *count*, *list*,
  *make a list*, *print*, *examine*, *generate*, *visit*.  He notes that
  *enumerate* may mean either task 1 or 2.  He settles for *generating*
  and *visiting* for task 2, when the list is not explicitly stored.
- Cameron (Notes on Counting, p. 1–2) settles with
  *counting* for task 1 and *generating* for task 2.  Later in the
  notes there are scattered instances of *enumeration*, which mostly
  seems to be synonymous with counting.
- Ruskey (Combinatorial Generation, 2003, p. iii) discusses
  the terminology for task 2.  He mentions *generate* and
  *enumerate* but notes that both are overloaded with other
  meanings.  For example, *generate* can mean generate uniformly
  at random, and *enumerate* can mean counting.  Ruskey also
  considers *listing* but settles with *generation*.
- Kreher & Stinson (Combinatorial Algorithms, 1999, p. 1) defines:
  *Generation*, construct all the combinatorial structures of a
  particular type – – A generation algorithm will *list* all the objects.
  *Enumeration*, compute the number of different structures of a particular type
  – – each object can be *counted* as it is generated.

Comment: Another term for task 2 is *traversing*, especially popular in the graph-theoretic context.

Comment: There is also *ranking* and *unranking* (see, e.g., Chapter 5 of Nicholas Loehr's *Bijective Combinatorics*), which is about explicitly constructing mutually inverse bijections between your set and $\left\{1,2,\ldots,n\right\}$ for some $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: See [bijective proof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bijective_proof). Namely if two (families of) finite sets have the same count, you may want to find a natural bijection.

Comment: Related question: if a set $A_n$ parameterized by $n$ is growing exponentially in $n$, then according to the usual way of thinking about things, it's impossible to efficiently list the elements of $A_n$; but I might count $\prod_{i=1}^{n}(1+x_i)$ as an "efficient representation" of all the subsets of $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$; I wonder if there has been any formal study of these kind of "efficient representations" (i.e., generating functions with all coefficients $0$ or $1$) which are somehow between listing and enumerating...

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is exactly what you're looking for, but the main topic of Herb Wilf's article [What is an Answer?](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2321713) is how to answer the question "How many ______ are there?"  His basic thesis is that an alleged answer to such a question is satisfactory only if it provides an algorithm whose computational complexity is significantly less than the best known algorithm for listing the elements.  More precisely, he introduces the following definitions:

$\mbox{Count$(n)$} = $ the complexity of the algorithm for calculating $f(n)$, whether it be given by a formula, an algorithm, et cetera, and

$\mbox{List$(n)$} = $ the complexity of producing all of the members of the set $S_n$, one at a time, by the speediest known method, and counting them.

> **Definition 1:** We will say that a solution of a counting problem is *effective* if
> $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\mbox{Count}(n)}{\mbox{List}(n)} = 0.$$

So Wilf certainly makes a clear distinction between the two tasks.  On the other hand, he does not devote much attention to *terminology* per se.

On a related but slightly different note, another important combinatorial task is *sampling* or *randomly generating* an element. The relation between counting and sampling is the topic of entire books, such as *Computational Complexity of Counting and Sampling* by István Miklós. In this context, the word *counting* is pretty consistently used for the task of computing $f(n)$, although this usage is largely *de facto*, whereas I understand you to be looking for *de jure* discussions.

Comment: Thanks; Wilf's article, which I was not aware of, is quite refreshing. I like his wry remarks around equation (2). Indeed Wilf is highlighting the distinction between the tasks. Stanley's EC1 (§1.1) has similar remarks about what it means to solve the "counting" task satisfactorily. --- Turning the attention to Wilf's choice of words, he uses *enumeration* and *count* for Task 1, and *list* and *produce* for Task 2. *Produce* was missing from my list.

Comment: And yes, although I phrased my question narrowly as "explicit considerations of *naming* the tasks", more generally I am also looking for works that consider the distinction of tasks 1 and 2, not necessarily their naming, so Wilf fits that bill. I might have phrased the question a bit wider.

Answer (score 7):

If I understand what you are looking for, I think (even though it's a noun) the term *combinatorial Gray code* can be an answer to your question. A combinatorial Gray code gives a means of listing a particular class of objects in an order which differ by a small amount (e.g. a classical Gray code which list binary strings by a single bit flip, listing subsets of size $k$ in an order which differ by one element, etc.). One reference is [A Survey of Combinatorial Gray Codes](https://doi.org/10.1137/S0036144595295272) by Carla Savage and the article begins with:

> One of the earliest problems addressed in the area of combinatorial algorithms was that of efficiently generating items in a particular combinatorial
> class in such a way that each item is generated exactly once. Many practical problems
> require for their solution the sampling of a random object from a combinatorial class
> or, worse, an exhaustive search through all objects in the class. Whereas early work
> in combinatorics focused on counting, by 1960 it was clear that with the aid of a computer it would be feasible to list the objects in combinatorial classes [73]. However, in
> order for such a listing to be possible, even for objects of moderate size, combinatorial
> generation methods must be extremely efficient. A common approach has been to try
> to generate the objects as a list in which successive elements differ only in a small
> way. The classic example is the binary reflected Gray code [45, 52] which is a scheme
> for listing all n-bit binary numbers so that successive numbers differ in exactly one
> bit.

The reference [73] is

> D. H. LEHMER, The machine tools of combinatorics, in Applied
> Combinatorial Mathematics, E. Beckenbach, ed., John Wiley & Sons, New
> York, 1964, pp. 5–31.

and is probably a example of what you are looking for. However, I can find this article online.

Comment: Thanks, this is a nice way of generating objects (Task 2) although not quite what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

I would say, as a first distinction, *enumerating* and *listing*  refer to ordinals (ex-numerare = producing an ordered bijection onto $[n]$, like a shepherd at sunset, emitting (*ex-mittere*) the numbers in order : $1,2,3,\dots$) while *counting* (cum-putare: putting together to reckon. I do not see etymologically the category of order in it) and *measuring* refer to cardinals.
We may count a bunch of apples of equal size using  a scale.

In this sense a generating series $\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k x^k$ enumerates; the inclusion-exclusion formula for $\big|\big(\cup_{i\in I} X_i\big)^c\big|$ counts. Indeed, the natural setting of it uses additive set functions, measures, probabilities, that are tools to weight sets.

Comment: +1 for the vivid imagery and the nice distinction between ordinals and cardinals. In this view perhaps we can say that *enumerating* is "abstract tallying": you imagine the bijection as a list, and argue what *would* happen if you went through the list and kept tally marks. ("Concrete tallying" would then be actually doing it.) Also, I was not aware that *counting* is etymologically linked to *com-puting*!